# While using angular libraries, ng-zorro does not have its classes applied

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using ng-zorro inside of an angular library I am creating. When I include it in another project that has ng-zorro included and working, the elements that are being provided through the library aren't being rendered properly.

Correctly rendered button

```
<button nz-button="" nztype="primary" class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary" ng-reflect-nz-type="primary"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><span>Primary</span></button>
```

Button provided through a library

```
<button _ngcontent-yfk-c13="" nz-button="" nztype="primary">Primary</button>
```

Is it not possible to include ng-zorro through a library?

Answer (score 1):

I faced this similar issue while creating an angular library which uses ng-zorro internally.
In my case i had to import the ng-zorro styles in the library styles files.

In the library folder i added the following import in the CSS/SCSS files and it worked for me.

```
@import "../../../../../../../node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.min.css";
```

Comment: This is actually what I had to do. I don't know why it wasn't finding it with the simple `@import '~node_modules/ng-zorro-antd...`